# String line by line

Tags: string, powershell, get-childitem, line-by-line

I have to listing files with some string from diferent location , but in the output I required path line by line. All it's OK if in the first locations are files more than one, but if is only one file and in other location are more files than all path are in the one line.

Example:

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" | Select-String "test" | group Path).Name
```

Output:

```
C:\temp\cca.msi
C:\temp\dfgfg.txt
C:\temp\dghghfgh.txt
```

Add second location:

```
$files += (Get-ChildItem "C:\temp2" | Select-String "test" | group Path).Name
```

Output:

```
C:\temp\cca.msi
C:\temp\dfgfg.txt
C:\temp\dghghfgh.txt
C:\temp2\file3.txt
C:\temp2\file4.txt
```

The above is correct.

Below it's wrong from me:

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" | Select-String "test" | group Path).Name
```

Output:

```
C:\temp\cca.msi
```

Add more paths:

```
$files += (Get-ChildItem "C:\temp2" | Select-String "test" | group Path).Name
```

Output in one line:

```
C:\temp\cca.msiC:\temp2\file3.txtC:\temp2\file4.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your first statement produces just a single result the variable `$files` contains a string, not an array. You can fix that by enforcing an array result, e.g. via the [array subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (`@()`):

```
$files = @((Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" | Select-String "test" | group Path).Name)
```

or by defining the variable as an array:

```
[array]$files = (Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" | Select-String "test" | group Path).Name
```

Answer (score 0):

That's working good , but i don't know why above code in my question didn't work.

```
$files=(Get-ChildItem "C:\temp","C:\temp2"  | Select-string "test"| group path).name
```

Comment: In your 2nd examle `$files` contains a string, if you `+=` to a string the result will also be a string unless you follow @AnsgarWiechers advice.